# BSOD ntoskrnl.exe with SSD and Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, ssd, bsod

I just bought a brand new SSD driver and installed windows 7.
Installed all the MOBA's drivers + VGA driver. But everytime I try to play some games it crashes and give me the BSOD !

- Hd Ssd Sandisk Plus® 240gb 530mb/s Sata 3
- MOBA: MSI b85-g43 Gaming
- VGA: Geforce gtx 960
- CPU: Core i5 4590 - Haswell

Already tried everything I found on the internet: Update/Reinstall Drivers, Update Bios, Check HD/SSD integrity... Nothing works and I don't know what else to try

Bios HDD settings are set to: UEFI + LEGACY 
The other option is "UEFI" only.

Obs2: I have 4 disks: (3 HDD + 1 SSD). One of this HDD are installed with Win7 
(I keep these 2 win7 instalations because I still need to backup the old sistem. I want to install linux further on this partition). While using this old Win7 installation, I get NO PROBLEM at all while playing games...

I thought it could be problem with cables but it only happens when I'm playing games.

DumpFiles: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kcp1hgxtgmgp8u/DumpFiles.rar?dl=0

Using BlueScreenViewer: 
[image: BlueScreenViewer Diagnostic]

More Specific:
[image: BlueScreenViewer]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the text of the BSOD *error code and descriptive text* (for purposes of searching).

Comment: Also, ntoskrnl.exe is probably a victim of the crashing code, not the culprit.

Comment: new case just happened and now we can add: `win32k.sys+118aac`

Comment: My vote: You have a bad hard drive or RAM.

Comment: @Twisty I think you've got it! See my answer.

Comment: Now my computer doesnt even show the bios screen =)  
Black screen only. What a luck...

Comment: Remove the new SSD. (You can just disconnect its SATA cable.) Does the behavior change?

Comment: Guys. I don't know what happened neither what to do I just want to sit and cry. Now even with my HDDs I get that bluescreen. Already lost 2 partitions full of data. Same `CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATOR` and `ntoskrnl.exe+3777 c0`. And it's no longer only playing games now it happens any time.

Answer (score 3):

052717-9360-01 says that a page fault (which is normally a benign event) occurred in kernel address space (also normally a benign event) but "The requested page of kernel data could not be read in" because "the disk subsystem has experienced a failure.".

It's very difficult for this status to be bogus. (Or, to put it more directly: It's probably correct. :) And the phrasing "disk subsystem" does include SSDs - they don't have a different message for SSDs; once you get above a fairly low level in the storage driver stack, they're all just "disks".

Both 052817-6364-01 and 052717-7113-01 say that a critical system process, specfically csrss.exe, died. In both cases the failure followed a pagefault in their user mode code. This is normally a benign event (pagefaults happen all the time).

Because these are minidumps, it is impossible to look further. (No memory contents from user mode are preserved in a minidump.) However if the "disk subsystem" is having problems these latter two dumps are consistent with the first one. An unresolved pagefault will cause the process that incurred it to die, and since the csrss process is a protected system process, that is fatal to the OS even though the problem didn't occur in kernel mode.

That it only occurs during gaming is probably associated with greater CPU activity and use of more memory.

Do you have a minidump of the latest crash? If you want more thorough analyses you need to enable kernel or full memory dumps, reboot, and wait for another crash. However at this point I would be troubleshooting the new SSD and any associated hardware.

You might also look at the system event log to see if any disk errors are being reported.

Answer (score 0):

Jamie Hanrahan said what you need to know but i want to add my experience, to help you.

i had the same problem, while i played game my computer stop and show me ntoskrnl error. i have found that it was my memory ram that was broken, i have changed them with new one and my pc run every game correctly.

maybe it wont help you but its a possibility that your ram are corrupted, even if the windows tools don't show that the memory is broken.

try with new memory i hope its the solution to your problem, it tooke me 3 month to find that solution was my solution so good luck.

Comment: Given that the system works fine when he runs off of the hard drive, I'd say the problem is unlikely to be in the RAM. It's the same RAM, after all.

Comment: yeah of course but its also one of the possibility cause for my problem, it was the same (not exactly with ssd and all) but my pc worked fine for all , search on internet, programing , etc but whent i started some game not all but just some game my pc crashed directly so maybe its the ssd but maybe the memory also ( he said: While using this old Win7 installation, I get NO PROBLEM at all while playing games...) maybe its fine cause the ram used for this purpose is correct and only the other parts are corrupt. but im maybe wrong

Comment: Now my computer doesnt even show the bios screen =)  
Black screen only. What a luck...